# Accessing Json object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I need help understanding this, I have a simple JSON string that my php script returns:
     `{ "questions" : "question1"}`

and my code for accessing it is :'

```
<script>

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     var jsond = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsond['questions'];
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsond.questions;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "make_exam.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
</script>
```

but for some reason beyond my knowledge, it keeps displaying undefined. i have tried understanding everything step by step but cant seem to see what i am doing wrong. Any help understanding it or advice on how to fix is appreciated.

my php script is down below,  i dont think the fault is here but what do i know.

```
        $file= "my.json";

        $json = json_encode(file_get_contents($file));
        if(empty($json))
        {
            echo "nothing";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $json;
        }
```

guys, this is the full html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="loadDoc()"> "Make Exam" </button>


 <p id="demo"> </p>

</body>



<script type="text/javascript">
function loadDoc() {


  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    var jsond = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
     alert(jsond);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<p>'+ jsond.questions +'</p>';
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "make_exam.php", true);
  xhttp.send();

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hi";

}
</script>







</html>
```

Comment: also.. i have two document.getElementByID statements because i tried both .

Comment: What does console.log(jsond) state?

Comment: Try opening Dev Tools (in Chrome) or Firebug (in Firefox) and check network tab to see the response, and console tab to check for JS errors. Then come back with more information :)

Comment: @AdamJeffers, I get {"questions" : "question1"}

Comment: What is undefined then?

Comment: I am just trying to display "question1".

Comment: I know mate but if jsond is valid JSON and has a key of "questions", it cannot be undefined.

Comment: yeah, that is what bothers me, i validated it with jsonlint.com and it was valid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the key "questions" exists in the file?
What does this return

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsond
```

Comment: i get this ; { "questions" : "question1"} , however i just want to see question1

Comment: If you get { "questions" : "question1"} as your data, the string is probably not parsed to a json object. An attempt to check the similar effect returns Object as output for jsond.
https://jsfiddle.net/zo24o3e0/